# Search for issues in current sprint in JIRA

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to pull all issues (resolved or not) from the current sprint and display that information. I am using a JIRA REST Java client to achieve this. I am quite new to JIRA and the JRJC so would like all the help I can get really.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
SearchResult allIssuesInSprint = restClient.getSearchClient().searchJql("sprint = \"" + 29 + "\" order by rank").claim();
Iterable<Issue> allIssues = allIssuesInSprint.getIssues();
for (Issue issue : allIssues) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + issue.getKey());
    System.out.println("Type: " + issue.getIssueType());
    System.out.println("Status: " + issue.getStatus());
    System.out.println("Priority: " + issue.getPriority());
}
```

Again, I am new to JIRA's JAR files, so I'm not certain on how to use them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is out put of above program.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(404), errorCollections=[]}
 at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:47)
 at Connection.main(Connection.java:30)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)`

Comment: That is where the error lies in the `SearchResult` line. I connect to the JIRA fine using Basic Auth

Comment: I have managed to solve this now as I was using the wrong arguments in the `searchJql()`. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @WillAshworth - glad you figured it out. Please note that it is perfectly fine and actually highly desired to post your own solution as an answer to your own question so that a) others can benefit from it too, and b) the question is marked as answered and the visibility of still unanswered questions is increased accordingly.

Comment: This solved my problem: `SearchResult allIssuesInSprint = restClient.getSearchClient().searchJql("sprint in openSprints() order by rank").claim();`. I used the `openSprints()` which is recognised as a Jql search param